# Log response time at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku adds a HTTP header called X-Request-Start. Its a unix timestamp.

I have a Rails 3.2 application at Heroku and want to log response time for HTTP requests.

Whats the latest point of possible integration in Rails to do:

```
start = Time.at(env['HTTP_X_REQUEST_START'].to_f / 1000.0).utc
response_time = Time.now.utc - start
```

I'm thinking of implementing a Rack middleware to calculate the response time.

Comment: Before you doing it I would ask why you doing it. just for some specific tests or for a bigger app monitoring system?

Comment: Monitoring. I've read NewRelic also uses the HTTP_X_REQUEST_START

Comment: If that so why not using new relic? I'm using it, it's much faster  that writing it in your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you aware that Heroku already logs your response time? In your terminal do `heroku logs -t --app your-app-name` and you'll see `service=xxxms` which is the number of miliseconds each request takes.